# Vertical Aligning - IE10 Flex box not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I have my center aligning working in all browsers that support it apart from IE10. I think that I have the syntax correct and that it does it support it. Could anyone help? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YnSyY/1/)

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: red;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-pack: center;
    -ms-box-align: center;
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E7F3FF;
    border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    color: #054B98;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 930px;
}
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need to specify row/horizontal direction unless you're overriding a previous column/vertical direction elsewhere.  Row/horizontal is the default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the right display value, but all of the other Flexbox properties you're using are wrong.  The proper translation would be like this:

```
body {
  background: red;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

However, if you're using Flexbox for vertical alignment purposes, this might be what you're needing instead:

```
body {
  background: red;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;

  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Note that box-align and flex-align/align-items are *not* equivalent properties, but they're performing the same task here.

Comment: I have had to add height: 100% instead of min-height as it was not working. Now it is fine in IE but in Firefox I have an imaginary 8px top margin on the body. I have a reset on my project so I don't know where this could be coming from

Answer (score 3):

Adding an explicit height seems to be the appropriate solution.

From: [Microsoft Connect - Min-height and flexbox (flex-direction:column) don't work together in IE 10 & 11-preview](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview)

> In all other browsers that support flexbox, a `flex-direction:column` based flex container will honor the containers `min-height` to calculate `flex-grow` lengths. In IE10 & 11-preview it only seems to work with an explicit `height` value.

Comment: Simple and well documented answer! Very useful.